# Get slug value from parameter using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

I have a url with format like this:

```
http://www.test.com/document/navigate/{{project_id}}/{{note_id}}
```

the value within `{{}}` will be filled with integer, like this for example

```
http://www.test.com/document/navigate/1/3
http://www.test.com/document/navigate/7/2
http://www.test.com/document/navigate/3
```

the value for `note_id` in the url is not mandatory, but i need to retrieve both for the `project_id` and `note_id`. how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression: `http[s]?:\/\/www.test.com\/document\/navigate\/([\d]+)[\/]?([\d]+)?[\/]?`.

Essentially it is laying out the protocol, hostname/domain, and the part of the path that we know. Then there are two capturing groups - the project ID and the note ID (optional).

You could use it like so:

```js
const url = 'http://www.test.com/document/navigate/1/3';
const parts = url.match(/http[s]?:\/\/www.test.com\/document\/navigate\/([\d]+)[\/]?([\d]+)?/);

console.log(parts[0]); // "http://www.test.com/document/navigate/1/3"  <- full match
console.log(parts[1]); // "1"  <- first group
console.log(parts[2]); // "3"  <- second group, which will be undefined if left off
```

> Note: this may not be a foolproof answer. I recommend trying out many other potential variations. Also be aware that this returns strings, so you may have to `parseInt()` or something if you want real numbers.

Here is a [Regexr](https://regexr.com/4sfkn) showing you how this works (this is how I mess around until I get it right).

Comment: I'd simplify this by ignoring the scheme, domain, etc. and just look at `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: @TroyCarlson Good tip, though the OP did not say they were checking the current URL, so I couldn't assume. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can make use of the part `navigate/` like the following way:

```js
var url1 = 'http://www.test.com/document/navigate/1/3';
var url2 = 'http://www.test.com/document/navigate/7/2';
var url3 = 'http://www.test.com/document/navigate/3';

function getValue(url){
  var arr = url.match(/navigate\/([^ ]*)/);
  arr = arr[arr.length - 1].split('/');
  if(arr.length == 1)
    return { project_id: +arr[0] };
  else if(arr.length == 2)
    return { project_id: +arr[0], note_id: +arr[1] };
  else
    return 'invalid';
}
console.log(getValue(url1));
console.log(getValue(url2));
console.log(getValue(url3));
```